# Showing success message on the redirected page

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working on change password. after i saved the updated or new  password i need to display the success message to the user in cakephp.

from change password method,after successful database operation  i am redirecting the user to logout method. logout method will delete the session and redirecting user to login method.

How to display the success message in Login method which is set in change password method

Comment: why would you logout a user when he/she is changing his/her password?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://book.cakephp.org/view/1313/setFlash. The setFlash function of the Session component was designed for this!

In the original controller action: `$this->Session->setFlash('Example message text');`

In the view of the other action: `echo $session->flash();`

Comment: It's always good if you put the `echo $session->flash();` into your default view so you don't have to worry about whether these messages are displayed or not.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is general and not for cakePHP specific alone.

While redirecting, you need to add some querystring in params.
like, if your login.php then

```
header("location:login.php?response=1");
```

and you need to read in login.php 
like this

```
if (isset ($_GET['response']))
{
    if ($_GET['response']=="1")
    {
      echo "Successfully logged out";
    }
}
```